# Upon conversion of DataTable to List, List displays multiple entries of the last row passed to it

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, mvvm

I have the following code:

```
public ObservableCollection<Promotes> GetThelist()
{
    ObservableCollection<Promotes> list = new ObservableCollection<Promotes>();
    Promotes promotes = new Promotes();
    DataTable DT= new DataTable();
    PromotesBusiness PromoteData = new PromotesBusiness();
    DT = PromoteData.GetOnlyData();

    if (DT.Rows.Count > 0)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < DT.Rows.Count; i++)
        {
            if (!Convert.IsDBNull(DT.Rows[i]["XPITEM"]))
            {
                promotes.T_item = Convert.ToDecimal(DT.Rows[i]["XPITEM"]);
            }

            promotes.T_uniq = DT.Rows[i]["XPUNIQ"].ToString();
            promotes.T_desc = DT.Rows[i]["XPDSC2"].ToString();

            if (!Convert.IsDBNull(DT.Rows[i]["XPPPCP"]))
            {
                promotes.T_Barcode = Convert.ToDecimal(DT.Rows[i]["XPPPCP"]);
            }

            list.Add(promotes);
        }
    }

    return list;
}
```

I have all the class (`Promotes`) properties set with `INotifyPropertyChanged` correctly (I think anyway). I have the `DataTable` DT declared with getters and setter and `INotifyPropertyChanged` also (I just declared it in this code so no one would wonder where it is coming from). Despite all this when I debug through the code it keeps setting all new rows added to the list with the last row picked up from the `DataTable` and consequently gives the result as the last row as a replacement for ALL rows in the `DataTable`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You create one instance of the `Promotes` object here: `Promotes promotes = new Promotes();` and add the same instance to the list, every time modifying the properties of that single object.

You should create your objects in the loop like this:

```
        for (int i = 0; i < DT.Rows.Count; i++)
        {
            Promotes promotes = new Promotes();

            if (!Convert.IsDBNull(DT.Rows[i]["XPITEM"]))
            {

                promotes.T_item = Convert.ToDecimal(DT.Rows[i]["XPITEM"]);
            }
            promotes.T_uniq = DT.Rows[i]["XPUNIQ"].ToString();
            promotes.T_desc = DT.Rows[i]["XPDSC2"].ToString();

            if (!Convert.IsDBNull(DT.Rows[i]["XPPPCP"]))
            {
                promotes.T_Barcode = Convert.ToDecimal(DT.Rows[i]["XPPPCP"]);

            }
            list.Add(promotes);
        }
```

Comment: thank you very much! That fixed it! never even thought of that.. Sorry I cant mark it as answer as I dont have enough reputation. That IS the answer though!

Comment: @sealions pretty sure you can always "accept" answers (the checkmark) you just can't vote up answers until a specific reputation